# SyntaxError: Unexpected token " [ " in JSON - Javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I am trying to retrieve the data from database. Whatever data I retrieve, I put that data into array and then apply `json_encode($data)`. I successfully get Array of Objects in the response `as a text`. But when I try to `JSON.parse(response)` I get an error which which says unexpected token `[`.

First I thought that the data will be already parsed so I tried `console.log(response[0])` in order to print the first object, but the result was `[`. I don't know what's the problem.

My question might be same to others, but I tried all possible solutions, and couldn't solve it through those answers.

**My PHP code :**

```js
public

function showDeposits($db_conn) {

  $sql = "SELECT * FROM `deposit`";

  if ($db_conn - > query($sql)) {
    $r = $db_conn - > query($sql);
    if ($r - > num_rows > 0) {
      $data = array();
      for ($i = 0; $i < $r - > num_rows; $i++) {
        $data[] = $r - > fetch_assoc();
      }
      echo json_encode($data);
    }
  }

}
```

**My Javascript code :**

```js
this.depositForm = function() {
  var form = document.querySelector("#dep_form");

  form.addEventListener("submit", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var json = {
      time: getTime().text,
      stamp: getTime().stamp,
      date: getDate().dateText,
      data: JSON.parse(toJSONString(this))
    };
    fetch("model.php", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(json)
    }).then(function(t) {
      t.text().then(function(res) {
        var j = JSON.parse(res);
        console.log(j);
      })
    })

  })

}
```

**The response**

[image: Result]

Comment: Try `console.log(res)` at the bottom there - sounds like it's not valid JSON.

Comment: Check it now @CertainPerformance

Comment: Yep, that's the issue. The `{"success":true}` should not be at the beginning there - remove whatever's adding it and things might work.

Comment: Oh,  I got the problem, I was sending two responses at one call...

Comment: Yes, gotcha .... Thank you mate :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instaed of using `.text()` and then parsing it, you just can use `.json`

```js
this.depositForm = function() {
  var form = document.querySelector("#dep_form");

  form.addEventListener("submit", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var json = {
      time: getTime().text,
      stamp: getTime().stamp,
      date: getDate().dateText,
      data: JSON.parse(toJSONString(this))
    };
    fetch("model.php", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(json)
    })
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((data) => console.log(data))
  })
}
```

small tip: You should use [promise chaining](https://javascript.info/promise-chaining).